# About Shemot 35:3

Tags: words, grammar-dikduk, translation, fire-burning, vayakhel

Why [Shemot 35:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0235.htm#3) is being translated as "do not burn fire" if the piel form of the verb "burn" in the Written Torah always being translated as "eradicate". Excellent example is [Dvarim 21:9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0521.htm#9).

If I understand correctly, Shemot 35:3 should be translated "do not eradicate fire".

What do you think?

Comment: what about exo 22 4 http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0222.htm#4

Comment: It can carry various meanings.

Comment: kindle does not fit the meaning anywhere. Its either burn, graze or eradicate.

Comment: @AleksandrSigalov On the contrary. The root in 35:3 means burn, and the verb conjugation of that root in the verse would be precisely translated as, "perform (pl.) an action causing ___ to burn" ("___" in this case is the object "fire"). I.e., "kindle," exactly as Yaacov Deane wrote.

Comment: Dear close-voters: Please do not vote to close questions about the Torah because they are about the language of the Torah. The Torah is a pretty important part of Judaism, and its language is a very important aspect of it.

Comment: Thanks Fred, but it does not make sense. Devarim 21:9 is being translated as eradicate. It is the same verb and the same form (piel) so I do not understand why it is different in Shemot 35:3?

Comment: Also, like I said, "kindle" does not fit in any of the verses.

Comment: http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1107.htm#18 http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1239.htm#9 both are read plainly as kindling/lighting fires.

Comment: @DoubleAA You seem to be ignoring my question... Are you saying that in Shemot 3:2 "the bush kindling in fire"? This does not make sense. Kindling does not fit anywhere. I know that there are different translations. I was asking about this word in particular in context of Shemot 35:3. Traditional translations of this verse are incorrect...

Comment: @AleksandrSigalov I don't think you understand what "kindling" means. Traditional translations are supported by context clues in Tanakh and do not seem incorrect.

Comment: Also, I was asking about Written Torah, not NK so I do not see how it is relevant here. In the Written Torah piel always "eradicate" not "burn". This is absolutely clear by all verses with this word in Devarim.

Comment: @AleksandrSigalov If you limit yourself to a sufficiently small set of data, you will always be able to exclude any examples which you don't like. Leaving out NK is not helpful if you are trying to understand how the word is used in biblical hebrew (Isa 7:18, Ez 39:9, maybe Lev 6:4). The fact is that the piel form is clearly used in the context of lighting fires in biblical hebrew. While the paal form may have seemed more natural, we do find paal forms becoming intensified on occasion in biblical hebrew, ex Hoshea 2:9.

Comment: @AleksandrSigalov What difference does it make that other examples of this root in *binyan pi'el* have other meanings? Once you know various definitions of the root, those definitions can apply to any rational verb conjugation. In this instance, the direct object is "fire," so the definition is obviously kindle. | Regarding the English definition of "תבערו" in my earlier comment, by the way, I meant to imply *pi'el*, not *hif'il* (just in case there was any ambiguity in my translation).

Answer (score 2):

The root (בער) as listed in Jastrow has several different meanings depending on the context.

For example, (בער) meaning to burn is found in Shemot Rabbah 2:5 which says, "since the bush burned..."
[http://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.2.5/he/Daat_Shemot_Rabbah?qh=הסנה%2Bבוער&lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all](http://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.2.5/he/Daat_Shemot_Rabbah?qh=%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%94%2B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%A8&lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)

And in Bamidbar Rabbah, parshat Naso, 9:46, which says, "for those burning with (desire for) idol worship..."
[http://www.sefaria.org/Bemidbar_Rabbah.9.46/he/Daat_Bemidbar_Rabbah?qh=לבוערים&lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all](http://www.sefaria.org/Bemidbar_Rabbah.9.46/he/Daat_Bemidbar_Rabbah?qh=%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D&lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)

But it also means 'to remove' as is found in Mishnah Sheviyit 7:7, which says, "they require removal...this is the general rule, everything which imparts taste must be removed from that which doesn't."

> וֶרֶד חָדָשׁ שֶׁכְּבָשׁוֹ בְּשֶׁמֶן יָשָׁן, יְלַקֵּט אֶת הַוֶּרֶד. וְיָשָׁן בְּחָדָשׁ, חַיָּב בַּבִּעוּר. חָרוּבִין חֲדָשִׁים שֶׁכְּבָשָׁן בְּיַיִן יָשָׁן, וִישָׁנִים בְּחָדָשׁ, חַיָּבִין בַּבִּעוּר. זֶה הַכְּלָל, כָּל שֶׁהוּא בְנוֹתֵן טַעַם, חַיָּב לְבַעֵר, מִין בְּשֶׁאֵינוֹ מִינוֹ. וּמִין בְּמִינוֹ, כָּל שֶׁהוּא. שְׁבִיעִית אוֹסֶרֶת כָּל שֶׁהוּא בְּמִינָהּ, וְשֶׁלֹּא בְמִינָהּ, בְּנוֹתֵן טָעַם:

It can also mean to consume or to clear away as is found in Bava Kamma 2b, which says, "And it shall consume (Shemot 22:4) denotes tooth, as expressed (in Melachim-1, 14:1) 'as the street sweeper  clears away his filth'

> ובער (שמות כב:ד) זו השן וכן הוא אומר (מלכים-א יד:י) כאשר יבער

And it also means 'to kindle or start a fire, as is found in Shemot 35:3, like it says, "לא תבערו אש בכל מושבתיכם", 'You will not kindle fire in all your dwellings..."

Comment: This post completely ignores the notion of Binyanim, and his hence really not helpful. Note as well that "clear away" and "remove" seem to be the same sense.

Comment: @DoubleAA According to the listing in Jastrow, all these usages apply to the Pi'el binyan that the OP asked about specifically.

Comment: בוער in your first two links is clearly Pa'al. The only example you have of the Piel form meaning burn is Exo 35:3, which is not helpful for the OP at indicating a pattern when all other instances of the Piel form you brought have to do with getting rid of.

Comment: I understand. But usually Jastrow is relying on the Aruch in regard to grammar usage for definitions. Nathan ben Yechiel, the early Rishon, is seen as extremely authoritative in this area. These were the exact citations Jastrow brought for the Pi'el binyan. You can disagree, but that's above my pay grade.

Comment: If you present this as your own thought then I can and will disagree by downvoting. If you present this as Jastrow's opinion, then I will not downvote. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1446/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks for the tip. I haven't understood what this whole 'meta' aspect is about. I'm assuming it's some kind of internet jargon. Does that mean how the site is supposed to be structured?

Comment: [meta] is a Q/A site _about_ Mi Yodeya. So questions about site policies, suggested features, support, bugs, etc. can be asked and answered there by members of the community or the Stack Exchange Team in our familiar Q/A format. You should check it out. Here's the Help Center's page describing it: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

Answer (score 0):

There are several perspectives bearing on the issue.

**Samaritan Pentateuch**

Instead of the word תְבַעֲר֣וּ found in the Masoretic Text, the [Samaritan Pentateuch](https://sites.google.com/site/interlinearpentateuch/exodus-shemot/chapter-35-1-15) instead understands the word to be תַבְעִירוּ, which is the first person plural of the same Hebrew verb, but in the *hifʿîl* (imperfect). Since the context is Moses speaking to the people, the reading would be, “We are not to extinguish fire in your dwellings on the Sabbath Day.” Although this reading appears awkward in both English and Biblical Hebrew, the verse would be consistent with [Leviticus 6:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0306.htm#5), which commands that the fire of the tabernacle never be extinguished.

**Babylonian Talmud**

The Babylonian Talmud addresses this very verse at great length (see for example, *Yevamoth*, [Folio 6B and Folio 7a](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_soncino.php?ms=Yevamoth&df=6b) or *Sanhedrin*, [Folio 35B and Folio 36A](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_soncino.php?ms=Sanhedrin&df=35b)). That is, the Talmud accepts the reading of the Masoretic Text, which is that fires will not be ignited on the Sabbath (under certain circumstances).

**Jerusalem Talmud**

The best Talmudic summary on this question appears in the Tractate *Beitzah* of the Talmud Yerushalmi, which is the tractate concerning festivals; in this regard, this Talmud also accepts the reading of the Masoretic Text, which is that fires will not be ignited on the Sabbath (under certain circumstances).

**Mekilta de-Rabbi Ishmael**

The [*the Mekilta de-Rabbi Ishmael*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mekhilta) is a classic collection of halakhic midrash to the Book of Exodus. This midrash compilation accepts the reading of the Masoretic Text, which is that fires will not be ignited on the Sabbath (under certain circumstances).

**Conclusion**

In summary, oral tradition leans toward the reading that the word תְבַעֲר֣וּ found in the Masoretic Text means do not ignite fire on the Sabbath (under certain circumstances).

Comment: Thanks. I know about traditional opinion. I was asking about what critical analysis of the text says. What you are proposing does not match the verses of the Written Torah. Sorry.

Comment: I know about SP btw. But I think Samaritans got it wrong. It should be piel because it is most intensive form. Hiphil is usually translated as "to graze" to "consume"